# Hyperplane through boundary of convex set

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

We can show that if $K\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is convex and $x\in\partial K$, then $x\in\partial\overline K$ and there is a $\zeta\in\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\}$ such that $$\langle\zeta,y-x\rangle\le0\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in K\tag1.$$

Now I've found the following theorem:

[image]

Is this theorem somehow different from the aforementioned result or can we prove it immediately from $(1)$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: If $D$ lies in $K$ then the half line $l$ cannot lie entirely in the other half space to $K$. Seems a bit sloppy to me.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess they mean that $l\setminus\{D\}$ lies entirely in the other half space.

Answer (score 0):

The result is false.

Let $K = ([-1,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]) \setminus ([0,1]\times \{0\} \times \{0\})$, $D=(0,0,0), l = [0,\infty) \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$.

$K$ is convex, $D \in \partial K$, $l \cap K = \emptyset$.

Any halfspace that contains $K$ must also contain $l$ since
$[-1,0) \times \{0\} \times \{0\} \subset K$.